# How to send selected objects parameters from drop down menu to a function in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

I have a drop down menu which fills with some doc names. Now when a person selects a document it calls onDocumentChange() method.

To fill the drop down menu i receive a object called result which is a list of doc objects from server.

```
<select id="documentSelect" onChange="onDocumentChange()">
<c:forEach items="${results}" var="result">
    <option id="${result.getDocDisplayURL()}"><c:out value="${result.getDocFn()}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Till this point it is strainght forward.

Now this doc object has some other attributes called date and time. Now when the user clicks any item from drop down menu  i want to send that particular items  time and date attributes to onDocumentChange() method. How can i do that.

I am guessing something like this

```
<select id="documentSelect" onChange="**onDocumentChange(result.date, result.time)**">
<c:forEach items="${results}" var="result">
<option id="${result.getDoc()}"><c:out value="${result.getText()}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be thinking that JavaScript runs together with Java/JSP. This is untrue. Java/JSP produces HTML and JavaScript is part of that HTML and works on the HTML DOM tree only. You need to make sure that your Java/JSP code produces HTML code containing exactly the information JavaScript needs to access. You can let Java/JSP print those variables as an attribute of a HTML element, like `<option>` in your case. You can use custom `data-*` attributes in HTML to append custom attributes.

```html
<option value="${result.doc}" data-date="${result.date}" data-time="${result.time}">
```

You can get the currently selected `<option>` element in JavaScript as follows

```js
var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
var doc = option.value;
var date = option.getAttribute("data-date");
var time = option.getAttribute("data-time");
// ...
```

You only need to change the `onchange` handler to pass the HTML `<select>` element itself

```
onchange="onDocumentChange(this)"
```

with

```js
function onDocumentChange(select) {
    // ...
}
```

By the way, why are you using separate properties for date and time instead of a single `java.util.Date` property? There's something wrong in the model design.

Comment: You are right. I am getting this result object from backend. I dont manage that. It has been existing for years. So using it without change. Thanks